# How to clean private data from browsers(temp files, caches, cookies) using Java on Windows

Tags: java, private

I think of doing something like a file cleaner for Windows with Java just for fun, I want it to be able to clean the temp files, caches... etc for the major browsers opera, ie, firefox.
I'm basically looking for some guidance to where to start my research, what are some good reads and basically what kind of libraries will I have to use (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/). It's written in python, but the actions should be easily converted to java. But then again, why not just use bleachbit itself?